# Is family planning considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

Pregnancy is considered [on-topic](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/pregnancy-questions) almost unanimously.  On the accepted answer, JBRWilkinson suggested that is is "a very good thing that people considering becoming parents proactively come to this site".

I am not a parent (yet) & before I pollute the site with off-topic questions, I'd like to know if the concept of family planning is considered relevant?

I guess some example questions may be around ovulation cycles or conception or financial preparation.

Comment: I though "family planning" was a euphemism for using contraceptives. I must admit I have no idea what *you* mean when you say it. Could you expand on this?

Comment: @Lennart: While "family planning" in the US is often used as a euphemism by those who favor the use of contraception, that was not its original meaning.  It once (well, when my grandparents were young, according to an older family member) meant a general strategy of having fewer children and investing heavily in the future of each, as opposed to the then-most-common strategy of birthing as many children as possible and hoping for the best.

Comment: @HedgeMage: It's still how to not have kids, which must be very off topic. :)

Comment: @Lennart The "how do I not get pregnant more than I want to" part is very off-topic, but the "how do I invest in the kids I do have" part is the whole point of the site. :)

Comment: By "family planning", I meant "planning a family"; that is, questions about the steps before becoming a parent (not just sexually, but emotionally, finanically, house-preparationally).

Comment: At first I was wondering if you were referring to your daughter/son's family planning, not yours!

Answer (score 4):

Getting pregnant seems to be agreed to be off-topic, per the question you already linked.  There's a proposal for a [sex Stack Exchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3303/everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-sex-but-were-afraid-to-ask) that would cover those sorts of things.

With regard to more general questions about what place in one's life one should be in before becoming a parent (emotionally, socially, financially, professionally, etc), *I* would consider them on-topic, but I'm not sure it's been discussed to the point of consensus yet.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between **getting** pregnant and **being** pregnant.
I feel the latter is on-topic, the former is not. So: No, family planning is off-topic in my opinion.