# Infertility questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Are questions concerning the infertility allowed in the Parenting site.
Because the solution of infertility problems will lead to Pregnancy, then Parenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pregnancy Questions](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/pregnancy-questions) are on topic.  Since infertility is directly related to pregnancy, questions on infertility should also be on topic, *provided* that they are not asking for specific medical advice, as that is explicitly off topic per our [faq](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/faq).