# Does parenting need a Diabetes tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked a question about gestational diabetes [Coping with gestational diabetes](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/9225/coping-with-gestational-diabetes)  and created a [diabetes](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diabetes) that is applicable for children, pregnant and nusring mothers (see wiki).

I am hoping the community is ok with this. I've included the wiki tag I created as a quote, to address possible dilemma of being off topic as to medical issues.

> For Type I (juvenile), Type II and gestational diabetes. Also
>   including impaired glucose tolerance. In children and pregnant and
>   nursing mothers.
>
> Diabetes has become an increasing problem in the developed world. It
>   can be a serious issue for children diagnosed with juvenile diabetes
>   and can be potentially life threatening. Both hypoglycemia and
>   hyperglycemia can become life threatening conditions.
>
> Gestational diabetes can affect the health of the unborn child. Some
>   side effects or poorly managed or untreated gestational diabetes are
>   (abnormally) large birth weight, hypoglycemia of the newborn,
>   respiratory distress, increased risk of premature birth,
>   overproduction of amniotic fluid.
>
> Blood sugar levels of a breast feeding mother are affected whenever
>   she feeds the baby.
>
> Some individuals have difficulty managing their blood sugar levels,
>   through no fault of their own, due to their metabolism.
>
> A diagnosis of diabetes in a child or a pregnant Mum can be an
>   overwhelming experience emotionally.
>
> Diabetic coma is an extreme and terrifying potential consequence of
>   poorly managed diabetes.

Comment: Just for any interested parents, I've create a proposal for [Living with Diabetes](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62091/living-with-diabetes)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is perfectly fine.

[Questions about pregnancy](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7/420) are considered on-topic, and gestational diabetes is a very real, and not terribly uncommon, pregnancy concern.

Diabetes is certainly something that can be relevant to parenting, particularly if one or more of your children have Type 1 Diabetes.  While specific medical advice is off topic, I see no problem with questions about anything from dealing with potential teasing related to diabetes, how to handle social and holiday functions where foods inappropriate for diabetics are being served (e.g. Halloween!), or even "How do I store my child's insulin while on vacation?".

Comment: thanks. I thought it would be ok. And type II diabetes in children is on the rise. Erm.. Do I accept this as answer in established beta with a mod?

Comment: I'd hold off on accepting.  Even though I'm a mod, I don't consider a moderator's voice to carry any extra weight in a meta thread using the [tag:discussion] tag.  Other moderators and users may have differing, or even opposite view-points, so it is best to give others a chance to chime in :)

Comment: Did you notice I'm trying extra hard to be good on [se]? omg O.o :) hey we need you on pets, there's some meta posts

Comment: I have noticed, and you're doing great :)  And I just replied to one of your meta posts on pets :)

Comment: Just to chime in, not even wearing my moderator hat but just as a normal user: I agree with this answer and upvoted it. @Skippy you don't have to accept the most voted answer, or any answer at all - just do whatever you're comfortable with. "Discussion" is exactly that - we're not writing laws here :-)

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun What?  No laws are being written on SE?  Sounds like our government here in the US earlier this month!  Hey btw sorry its been so long.

Comment: @balancedmama It's great to see you back here... we missed you!

Answer (score 2):

While I don't personally have a problem with tag and I see you've already accepted the other answer, I just wanted to chime in with the thought that it might make more sense to come up with a slightly less specific tag that could encompass other disorders as well (perhaps in addition to the diabetes tag, but that many example questions might use).

I could see how coping with a variety of maladies during pregnancy as well as how to help children cope with things that affect what they can eat or how they play/clebrate could have a lot of over-lap.

For example, I could see Restricted-diets being useful to those with kids with diabetes, severe food allergies, AND other disorders such as celiac's.  I wouldn't want to be the one trying to figure out ALL the related tags, but if there was one umbrella tag that people would likely find and use, it might be even more helpful.

Comment: yes, good thinking. Now I am not sure. There is a general tag for health.. hmm what tag name do you suggest

Comment: I think there is one for health and as far as ideas - I think some brainstorming and adding would be good in general.  I'm going to add restrictive-diet as that is the connection I made.

Comment: While I agree with this, I think in some sense the field of medical-ish questions will expand in ways we can't predict.  So the right tags to cover what comes up may suggest themselves better later.  It may make sense to take a little bit of a wait-and-see approach.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the community is *VERY CLEAR* about the difference between "medical advice" and "helpful advice about living with diabetes of various sorts".

Once you have diabetes tags what about Asthma, which has similar requirements for handling hardware for the illness?

Comment: I think you are asking a new question within your answer. I agree about the VERY CLEAR